# g-tensor and hyperfine tensor for nitroxide spin label with 15N

Tags: chemical-biology, radicals, isotope, databases, epr-spectroscopy

Does anyone know where I can find numerical data for the $g$ tensor and hyperfine tensor for a nitroxide spin label where the nitrogen-14 atom has been replaced by a nitrogen-15 atom?

I'm really getting lost in the literature. I come from outside the field of biological EPR so it's very difficult to find the information I need from the plots and the jargon.

Comment: Some data [here](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00723-009-0064-9) might be of use - it's actually a good paper with a large theoretical component and you can at least get ballpark numbers for $g$, A, and D.

Comment: This could certainly be useful for getting familiar with the nomenclature, thank you. However, I don't think it discusses the case of 15N, unless I'm mistaken. Maybe the numbers are not too different from 14N, but I don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found this book by Derek Marsh:

Derek Marsh, "Spin-Label Electron Paramagnetic Resonance" (CRC Press, Boca Raton, 2019). DOI: [10.1201/9780429194634](https://doi.org/10.1201/9780429194634).

It has many tables and the basic theory going with them. I would strongly recommend it.